# Dinamically create a link using ACF (Advanced Custom Field) custom value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, whatsapp

I'm trying to create a custom link based on a custom field, something like this:

`<a href='htts://wa.me/55[acf field="phone-number"]?text=more%20text%here'>Whatsapp</a>`

Maybe creating another shortcode loading de ACF field, but I don't know how do that.

I've tried do customized the following code, but without success:

```
function diwp_enclosed_shortcode_social_links($attr, $content){
 
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
     
            'url' => '#',
            'color' => '#F0F',
            'textsize' => '16px'
 
        ), $attr );
 
    $output = '<a href="'.$args['url'].'" style="color:'.$args['color'].'; font-size:'.$args['textsize'].' ">'.$content.'</a>';
    return $output;
 
}
 
add_shortcode( 'enclosed_social_links', 'diwp_enclosed_shortcode_social_links' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello as explained in the [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/#get-a-value-from-a-specific-post) you can load the acf field just by adding the id of the post it is associated with:

```
$value = get_field( "phone-number", 123 );
```

You can find the post id in the url on the edit post in the backend for example: https://your-url/wp-admin/post.php?post=161&action=edit

In that case we will get the phone-number from the post 161 and it should all be set, if the whole thing need to be done dynamically then we can just use [get_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/#get-a-value-from-the-current-post) because we should be in the page in which the field is saved.

Merry christmas!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with the following code:

```php
function numero_whatsapp_dinamico( $attr ) {
    $post_id      = $attr['post_id'];
    $phone_number = get_field( 'numero_de_whatsapp', $post_id );

    $output = '<a class="botao-whatsapp-estabelecimento" href="https://wa.me/55' . $phone_number . '?text=more%20text%20here" ">Whatsapp</a>';
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'numero_whatsapp_estabelecimento', 'numero_whatsapp_dinamico' );
```

Hope It'll help someone else with the same problem.